# How to ignore code block/expression style in editorconfig ( C# )

Tags: formatting, rider, editorconfig

I am creating my own .editorconfig configuration. I am almost done, but I can't figure out how to change method layout.

Sometimes I write code with code block, like:

```cs
public string SomeMethod() 
{
    return "Some string";
}
```

but sometimes using expression body, like:

```cs
public string SomeMethod() => "Some string";
```

The problem is that I don't want to make any rule that will force me to use one of those.

I am using Jetbrains RiderIDE and want to also use file cleanup - currently, the cleanup action modifies my methods, and forces one of the selected options configured in Rider/editorconfig.

Is there a way to ignore it?

There is no way to ignore it in IDE settings [image]